# Can i clone a running vbox machine?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, clone

Is it possible to clone a running VBox machine?

I need this because I can't turn off the machine during its purpose so I was wondering if something like that is possible?

I tried by cloning the snapshot but that option is not available while the VBox machine is running.

Im using Windows7 and the machine im trying to clone Linux machine.

Answer (score 1):

In other virtualization programs you have the option to export the VM, make an online snapshot and roll forward the export. I do not believe this is possible in Virtual Box.